# ReferenceError: Document is not defined when trying to use medium-editor in svelte app

Tags: javascript, html, sveltekit, medium-editor

I'm trying to use the [`medium-editor`](https://github.com/yabwe/medium-editor) in my Svelte application as follows.

```js
<script lang="ts">
  import { onMount } from 'svelte';
  import 'medium-editor/dist/css/medium-editor.min.css';
  import 'medium-editor/dist/css/themes/default.min.css';
  import MediumEditor from 'medium-editor';

  let editor;

  onMount(() => {
    editor = new MediumEditor('#editable', {
      // medium-editor options can be added here
    });
  });

</script>

<div class="app">
    <div id="editable" contenteditable="true">
        <!-- Your initial content goes here -->
      </div>
</div>

<style>
    
</style>
```

However, when running the application, I'm getting the following error, despite `onMount` function has been used.

> ReferenceError: document is not defined
> at Object. (/Users/pavindu/Projects/chronicle/app/node_modules/medium-editor/dist/js/medium-editor.js:6:22)
> at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1256:14)
> at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1310:10)
> at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1119:32)
> at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:960:12)
> at ModuleWrap. (node:internal/modules/esm/translators:169:29)
> at ModuleJob.run (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:194:25)

Comment: What code does the browser report as being the origin of the error? There's no mention of "Document" in the code you posted.

Comment: Sorry, I have missed to add the stack trace. The error is originating from the medium-editor package.

Comment: So it looks like you're trying to use the package in Node, but it is clearly designed to be used in a browser environment. There is no `document` global symbol in a Node context (unless you install and use a DOM package). What is it that you intend to do with the "medium-editor" package?

Comment: I want to render a medium-like editor in my app and that's what I used this package for. Is there a way to make that specific page client side rendered? In next.js, I could easily do this by adding `use client;`, but there is no such straightforward way in svelte it seems.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a code to determine if you are in the browser

```
import { browser } from '$app/environment';

onMount(() => {
  if (browser) {
    editor = new MediumEditor('#editable', {
      // medium-editor options can be added here
    });
  }
```

or a better way would be per the sveltekit docs you can import in the `onMount` method

```
import { onMount } from 'svelte';

onMount(async () => {
    let editor = await import('medium-editor');
    editor = new MediumEditor('#editable', {
      // medium-editor options can be added here
    });
});
```

Take a look at the [SvelteKit FAQ How do I use a client-side only library that depends on document or window?](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/faq#how-do-i-use-x-with-sveltekit-how-do-i-use-a-client-side-only-library-that-depends-on-document-or-window)

Comment: The code is already using `onMount`, the `browser` check is redundant. The problem is probably the import. Also, using `async` directly on the `onMount` callback is a pitfall, because you then cannot return a destroy cleanup function from it.